# How to get every third Friday of every third month in R

Tags: r

Trying to get the date for the third friday of every three months in the year (March, June, Sept, Dec) from 2018 to 2020. However, my current code just gives me every 3rd friday. So `b`'s output will actually give me two Friday dates in June 2018. See code below:

```
allDates = seq(from = as.Date("2018-01-01"), to = as.Date("2020-07-01"), by = "days")
df = data.frame(allDates)
df$Date = weekdays(df$allDates)
Day = data.frame()
fridays = data.frame()

a = df[month(allDates)%in%c(2,5,8,11) & weekday(allDates)==5,]
b = a[seq(from = 3, to = nrow(a), by = 3),]
```

How would i then assign different variables to specific dates? for example, x = third friday of March and Sept. and y = third friday of March, June, Sept, and Dec?

Comment: In `c(2,5,8,11)`  is not March and 5 is not June. Is this right?

Comment: I thought months started from 0? i.e., 0 = Jan, 1 = Feb,..., Dec = 11

Comment: `help('strptime')` format `"%m"` says *Month as decimal number (01–12).*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following base R code outputs the 3rd Fridays of the required months. The output month names are in my current locale but the code itself does not depend on it.

```
friday3 <- function(start.year, end.year){
  d <- seq(ISOdate(start.year - 1, 12, 1), ISOdate(end.year, 12, 1), by = "3 month")[-1]
  d <- as.Date(d)
  res <- lapply(d, function(x){
    s <- seq(x, by = "day", length.out = 28)
    i <- format(s, "%u") == "5"
    s[i][3]
  })
  
  res <- Reduce(c, res)
  data.frame(Month = format(d, "%Y-%B"), Day = res)
}
```

My locale is not English, so I have to set an English language locale to test it, but the code itself does not depend on locale.

```
#ol <- Sys.getlocale("LC_TIME")
#Sys.setlocale("LC_TIME", "en_US.UTF-8")

friday3(2018, 2020)
#            Month        Day
#1      2018-March 2018-03-16
#2       2018-June 2018-06-15
#3  2018-September 2018-09-21
#4   2018-December 2018-12-21
#5      2019-March 2019-03-15
#6       2019-June 2019-06-21
#7  2019-September 2019-09-20
#8   2019-December 2019-12-20
#9      2020-March 2020-03-20
#10      2020-June 2020-06-19
#11 2020-September 2020-09-18
#12  2020-December 2020-12-18
```

And back to mine.

```
#Sys.setlocale("LC_TIME", ol)
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for something like this? (data is based on the three first lines of your code).

The three important parameters are the *month* and *date* you want to filter (`c(3,6,9,12)` and `'Friday'` in  `filter(month(allDates)%in%c(3,6,9,12) & Date == 'Friday')`) and the *nth* position of the day (`3` in `summarise(col=nth(allDates,3))`).

```
library(lubridate)
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  filter(month(allDates)%in%c(3,6,9,12) & Date == 'Friday') %>% 
  mutate(month=month(allDates),
         year=year(allDates)) %>% 
  group_by(year,month) %>% 
  summarise(col=nth(allDates,3))

# A tibble: 10 x 3
# Groups:   year [3]
    year month col       
   <dbl> <dbl> <date>    
 1  2018     3 2018-03-16
 2  2018     6 2018-06-15
 3  2018     9 2018-09-21
 4  2018    12 2018-12-21
 5  2019     3 2019-03-15
 6  2019     6 2019-06-21
 7  2019     9 2019-09-20
 8  2019    12 2019-12-20
 9  2020     3 2020-03-20
10  2020     6 2020-06-19
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, we create a month column which extracts the month from the allDates column. Package lubridate and function month() is used for this purpose

After that, we filter for the months you have asked for (March, June, September, December) and the day friday.

After that, we calculate row_nr. This column is helpful because we can apply the modulo operator afterwards to figure out every third Friday.

Then, we select the relevant cases which fulfill the criterion every third Friday from the previously specified months.

```
 library(tidyverse)
 library(lubridate)
    


fridays <- df %>% 
  mutate(month = month(allDates)) %>% 
  filter(month %in% c(3, 6, 9, 12), Date == "Friday") %>% 
  group_by(month) %>% 
  mutate(row_nr = row_number(),
         relevant = ifelse(row_nr%%3 == 0, 1, 0)) %>% 
  filter(relevant == 1)

 fridays
# A tibble: 12 x 5
# Groups:   month [4]
   allDates   Date   month row_nr relevant
   <date>     <chr>  <dbl>  <int>    <dbl>
 1 2018-03-16 Friday     3      3        1
 2 2018-06-15 Friday     6      3        1
 3 2018-09-21 Friday     9      3        1
 4 2018-12-21 Friday    12      3        1
 5 2019-03-01 Friday     3      6        1
 6 2019-03-22 Friday     3      9        1
 7 2019-06-07 Friday     6      6        1
 8 2019-06-28 Friday     6      9        1
 9 2019-09-13 Friday     9      6        1
10 2019-12-13 Friday    12      6        1
11 2020-03-13 Friday     3     12        1
12 2020-06-19 Friday     6     12        1
```

Comment: Have you checked that this code works? Show the `head(fridays)` to demonstrate that your code answers the question. Note Stack Overflow  is an English language site; I suspect `Date == "Freitag"` may only work for German language dataframe.

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.